# Is it right that the fundamental recurrence of an arbitrary continued fraction cannot be proved without induction?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, continued-fractions

Let $\dfrac{A_{n}}{B_{n}}$ be the $n^{th}$ convergent (approximant)
$$

\frac{A_{n}}{B_{n}}=b_{0}+\dfrac{a_{1}}{b_{1}+\dfrac{a_{2}}{b_{2}+\dfrac{a_{3}}{\begin{array}{c}
b_{3}+ \\ 
\\ 
\end{array}
\begin{array}{cc}
\ddots  &  \\ 
& 
\end{array}
+\dfrac{a_{n-1}}{b_{n-1}+\dfrac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}}}}}
$$
of a continued fraction. $A_{n}$, $A_{n-1}$, and $A_{n-2}$ satisfy the
recurrence
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{n} \\ 
B_{n}
\end{pmatrix}
&=&
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{n-1} & A_{n-2} \\ 
B_{n-1} & B_{n-2}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
b_{n} \\ 
a_{n}
\end{pmatrix}
\quad \text{for }n\geq 1, \\
&& \\
\text{and }
\begin{pmatrix}
A_{-1} & A_{0} \\ 
B_{-1} & B_{0}
\end{pmatrix}
&=&
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & b_{0} \\ 
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
,
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
which may be proved by induction.

**Question**: Is there a non inductive proof?

EDIT: I changed the title. Based on the comment below by anon

> The numerators and denominators are defined inductively - and I don't
>   believe you'll find an explicit formula for the n-th convergent of an
>   arbitrary continued fraction (though maybe of particular ones with
>   specific patterns, like $\varphi$) - so I don't see any other way to
>   say prove anything about the convergents except inductively.

I reformulate the question to

**Question**: Is it right that the fundamental recurrence of an arbitrary continued fraction cannot be proved without using mathematical induction?

Comment: I'm not sure what sort of answer you're looking for; it's a recurrence relation, so induction seems very natural to me. You might be able to work out $A_n$ and $B_n$ explicitly and just do algebra, but I reckon finding formulas for $A_n$ and $B_n$ would require induction.

Comment: @Billy: The proof if exists might make further mathematical conclusions.

Comment: The numerators and denominators are defined inductively - and I don't believe you'll find an explicit formula for the $n$-th convergent of an arbitrary continued fraction (though maybe of particular ones with specific patterns, like $\phi$) - so I don't see any other way to say prove anything about the convergents except inductively.

Comment: @anon: That's make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A continued fraction may be defined

1. as a composition of linear fractional transformations;
2. as an expression of the form
   $$b_0 + \cfrac{a_1}{b_1 + \cfrac{a_2}{b_2 + \cfrac{a_3}{b_3 + \cfrac{a_4}{b_4 + \ddots\, \quad }}}}$$
3. by the fundamental recurrence itself.

In both cases 1 and  2 the recurrence relation is proved by induction, as far as I have seen, namely in recent books.

For a generic continued fraction I now think there is no other way of deriving the fundamental recurrence either from 1 or 2.